TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') (Material Tailwind)
I'm working on a small project using material-talwind, but I'm getting the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') and I still can't fix it.
Error img
It seems like it reports an error in material-tailwind's theme.js
Error
ThemeProvider
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                    <RouterProvider router={router}/>
                </Suspense>
            </Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);

package.json
{
  "name": "client-ver-2",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^2.1.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.96",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.42",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.4",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwind-variants": "^0.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }
}


Theme
module.exports = withMT({
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js, ts,tsx}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: graviadTheme.colors,
            fontFamily: graviadTheme.fontFamily,
            fontSize: graviadTheme.fontSize,
            boxShadow: graviadTheme.boxShadow,
            borderRadius: graviadTheme.borderRadius,
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        require("tailwindcss"),
        require("autoprefixer"),
    ],
});

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5"
    /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "esnext"
    /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ]
    /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
     "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
    /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
//     "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true
    /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "build"                      /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    // "rootDir": "src"                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
     "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
     "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
     "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true
    /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true
    /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true
    /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true
    /** Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts). */,
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node"
    /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
     "baseUrl": "src",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
     "paths": {
       "@grvd/components/*": ["grvd/components/*"],
     },                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true
    /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true
    /* Allows for importing, extracting types from and generating .json files*/

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
}

How can I fix it, I try to use some other version of material tailwind but not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
